# set nickname of fetched user discord js

Tags: node.js, discord, fetch, undefined

I'm trying to set nickname of discord user to name that I get from database

```
client.guilds.cache.forEach((guild) => {
        console.log(guild.name + " - " + guild.id);
        if (guild.name == "SERVER.COM") {
                variableguild = guild;
        }
});
```

```
variableguild.members.fetch().then(r => {
        r.forEach(r => {
                let userid = r.user
                database.query("SELECT nick FROM relacje WHERE user = " + r.user.id, (err, row) => {
                        if (err) return console.log("Crit error: " + err);
                        if (row[0]) {
                                if (row[0].nick !== "XEX") {
                                        var pobranygosczdc = client.users.fetch(r.user.id);
                                        pobranygosczdc.member.setNickname(row[0].nick);
                                }
                        }
                })

        })
});
```

Above code is running in `client.on('ready', () => {`

I'm trying to figure out what the problem is. I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'setNickname' of undefined
```

discord js 12.5.1

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First `client.users.fetch()` returns a promise. so you should work with `await` or `.then()`.

[Documentation for .fetch()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/UserManager?scrollTo=fetch)

---

The second problem is that a user has no member propertie, because they always have to be in relation to a server(guild). So what you can do is something like

```
    variableguild.members.fetch().then(guildMembers => {
    guildMembers.forEach(guildMember => {
        let memberId = guildMember.id;

        database.query("SELECT nick FROM relacje WHERE user = " + memberId, (err, row) => {
            if (err) return console.log("Crit error: " + err);
            if (row[0]) {
                    if (row[0].nick !== "XEX") {
                            guildMember.setNickname(row[0].nick);
                    }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

[User class Properties/methods](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User)